# redirect whole Folder to Root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I've looked everywhere and am unable to find a solution.

I want to redirect several folders (and all of their contents, including subfolders) to the root of the website.

Example of **what should happen**:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/ -> http://www.domain.com/
http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/ -> http://www.domain.com/
```

Example of **what happens now**:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/ -> http://www.domain.com/ (works!)
http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/ -> http://www.domain.com/subfolder/ (doesn't work!)
```

What's wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```